# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[The first full election](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Coffee has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the winners are:

[image: JJJ]

[image: Stephie]

[image: luser droog]

Congrats to [the existing crew](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) for winning re-election and welcome to the team, luser droog — please thank them all for volunteering!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5098854625050624).